# QuickSort not working (segmentaion fault)

Tags: c++, quicksort

Can anyone please tell me why this code is not working. It keeps giving me a segmentation fault and I cant find out exactly where the error actually lies. It will be really grateful. I've been at it for hours but still cant figure it out.

```
vector<long> QuickSortArray(vector<long> nums)
{
        long arr[nums.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
                arr[i] = nums[i];
        }
        if(nums.size() == 1)
        {return nums;}
        else
        {
                long pivot = arr[0];
                int m = 0;
                int n = 0;
                for(int j = 1; j < nums.size(); j++)
                {
                        if(arr[j] < pivot)
                        {
                                m++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                n++;
                        }
                }
                long left[m+1];
                long right[n+1];
                int a = 0;
                int b = 0;
                for(int j = 1; j < nums.size(); j++)
                {
                        if(arr[j] < pivot)
                        {
                                left[a] = arr[j];
                                cout<<left[a]<<endl;
                                a++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                right[b] = arr[j];
                                cout<<right[b]<<endl;
                                b++;
                        }
                }
                vector<long> l;
                vector<long> r;
                for(int x = 0; x < m+1; x++)
                {l.push_back(left[x]);}
                for(int y = 0; y < n+1; y++)
                {r.push_back(right[y]);}
                l = QuickSortArray(l);
                r = QuickSortArray(r);
                vector<long> ret;
                for(int h = 0; h < l.size(); h++)
                {ret.push_back(l[h]);}
                ret.push_back(pivot);
                for(int k = 0; k < r.size(); k++)
                {ret.push_back(r[k]);}
                return ret;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the steps suggested at http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ?

Comment: `long arr[nums.size()];` I am not sure that this is even legal in C++. Try with `vector<long> arr(nums.size());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the case nums.size() == 0 and not nums.size() == 1 in the beginning.

```
if(nums.size() == 0)
    {return nums;}
```

Also, I think that you should write

```
long left[m];
long right[n];
```

And why don't you use exclusively vectors ? Using C-like arrays seems more like a way to look for troubles here.